# Read Windows Folder/File-Permissions with Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, permissions

I would like to get a list of Folder-Permissions in Ruby. As input i give e.g. `'c://temp'` and output should be, which user/group has rights and which rights.

and the next thing is to pass a second parameter (user or group) so that ruby can tell me on which folder this group or user has rights (reading / writing etc.).

cant find anything and `get_permissions` from `win32-file-gem` doesn't work.

thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use win32-file-stat gem. For example:

```
require 'win32/file/stat'
f = File::Stat.new("c:/temp")
p f
```

will give you something like this:

`#<File::Stat archive=false atime=1970-01-01 04:00:00 +0400 blksize=4096 blockdev=false blocks=0 compressed=false ctime=1970-01-01 04:00:00 +0400 dev=C: encrypted=false gid=0 hidden=false indexed=true ino=0 mode=040755 mtime=1970-01-01 04:00:00 +0400 nlink=1 normal=false offline=false rdev=2 readonly=false reparse_point=false size=0 sparse=false system=false temporary=false uid=0`

where you could see `mode`,`gid` and `uid` as numbers, accessed by `` `f.mode ``,`f.gid` and `f.uid` respectively.